# Accessing Twitter Ads API from R using twitteR package?

Tags: r, twitter, ads

I am trying to access Twitter Ads API from R, using twitteR package to authenticate, however, I cannot move further, any ideas, did anybody try it using a similar approach? Current error I get as this one (below) My app is whitelisted for ads, and my credentials work through Twurl, using this credential I can without problem access public API, but struggle with Ads one. Thanks!

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
library(twitteR)
library(BBmisc)
library(httr)

appname <- “xxxxx”
api_key <- “xxxxxxx”
api_secret <- “xxxxxxxx”
access_token <- “xxxxxxx”
access_secret <- “xxxxxx”
account_id <- “xxxxxxx”

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret, access_token, access_secret)

campaign_id <- itostr(18257572,base=36)

reach_campaign.request <- GET(“https://ads-api.twitter.com/2/stats/accounts/xxxxxxx/reach/campaigns?start_time=2018-06-10T00:00:00+01:00Z&campaign_ids=xxxxx&end_time=2018-06-15T00:00:00+01:00Z”,
query = list(granularity = “DAY”,
metric_groups = “ENGAGEMENT”,
placement = “ALL_ON_TWITTER”),
accept_json(),
config(token = access_token))
```

Comment: You should not use `twitteR` anymore! The package is outdated and can not handle recent in Twitter API. You should use the latest github version of `rtweet` instead: http://rtweet.info/

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: You may also access to twitter ads data through services like windsor.ai